# Is there a way to conditionally add attribute-value pairs to an element declaration in Angular2+?

Tags: angular, primeng, ng-template

I'm trying to create a wrapper template that will contain certain attribute-value pairs based on a certain condition. Appending attribute-value pairs would be the most elegant solution I can think of...

```
<ng-template #wrapper let-size="size">
    <custom-component {if size === 'XL', [xlInput]="someVal"}
                      {if size === 'L', [lInput]="otherVal"}
                      {if size === 'M', class="medium"}
                      etc... >
    </custom-component>
</ng-template>
```

Something like the pseudo-code above.

I have explored conditionally applying directives using the [attr.directive-name]="condition ? someVal : null" approach, but this isn't robust to handle all of my use-cases.

For more context, I am working with primeNG's p-table. My wrapper template is to generate a specific type of table based on an input condition (ie. condition 1 creates a table where rows are selectable, condition 2 creates an un-selectable table, etc).

I'm hoping there is some solution similar to the pseudo-code below.

```
<ng-template #table let-tableType="tableType"
    <p-table class="myTable" dataKey="var1" [columns]="var2" [value]="var3"
             {if tableType === 'selectable': [(selection)]="var4"}
             {if tableType === 'selectable': (onRowSelect)="someFunc()"}
             {if tableType === 'selectable': (onRowUnselect)="someOtherFunc()"}
             {if tableType === 'selectable': (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="anotherFunc()"}>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </p-table>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a couple of different components for your use cases, if the differ that much. And use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` structural directives to select the right case to use. Don't use one component for them all, it will get huge and out of control if you have a lot of use cases.